# How do I find all complex numbers that are solutions of $z^3 +8i=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

My workbook has answers in the standard form $a+bi$. I would assume that to solve this, I would expand the complex number $z$ into trigonometric form to deal with that exponent. This is what I have so far using De Moivre's Theorem:

$(r^3(\cos(3\theta)+i\sin(3\theta)) +8i=0$.

However, I do not know where to go from here. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You have $r^3\cos(3\theta)+r^3i\sin(3\theta)=-8i$.  Equate real and imaginary parts

Comment: I cannot imagine there is not a similar example in your book

Comment: Unfortunately, there are not. The book is Elements of Modern Algebra 8th Ed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You found that $r^3 \cos(3\theta)+i r^3 \sin(3\theta)=-8i$. We have that $|r^3 \cos(3\theta)+i r^3 \sin(3\theta)|=|-8i|$ and therefore $r^3=8$ and $r=2$.

Now we have $\cos(3\theta)+i \sin(3\theta)=-i$. Since real part on the right side is $0$, it must be $0$ on the left too. Since imaginary part on the right side is $-1$, it must be $-1$ on the left side too. We have that $\cos(3\theta)=0$ and $\sin(3\theta)=-1$. This gives us: $$3\theta=2k\pi+\frac{3\pi}{2}$$
$$\theta=\frac{2k\pi}{3}+\frac{\pi}{2}$$.
If it looks like there are infinitely many solutions, it's an illusion.
Since $z$ depends only on the $\sin$ and $\cos$ of the angle $\theta$, we will have the same $z$ for $\theta$ and $\theta+2k\pi$. There are 3 solutions for every $\theta \in (0,2\pi)$ that satisfies the condition.

Comment: Your trick is new to me: equating the reals and imaginaries. How come you don't equate the entire real component on the LHS with that on the RHS? i.e. $r^3cos(3\theta)=8$?

Comment: @Edison:  the real part of $-8i$ is $0$, so it would be $r^3\cos(3\theta)=0$

Comment: @Edison Well, you won't get far with solving any equations if you don't use this "trick". I don't do it with the entire real component because I've reduced the equation first (I found that $r=2$). After I reduce the equation $\cos(3\theta)$ is my entire real component. I could equate real and imaginary components at the beginning, but this wouldn't give me the easier solution. I'd still have to use the norm of the complex number.

Comment: That makes sense. Am I right in that $k=0,1,2$? Then $\theta=3\pi/6, 7\pi/6, 11\pi/6$.

Comment: It's really, really, neat if you view this graphically.  If you ignore thee size, $8$, and just look at this on a unit circle.  $0 - 8i$ will have an angle of $-90^\circ = \frac {3\pi}2=\frac {-\pi}2$.  You divide that angle in three to get one of the angles.  The other two angles are equidistance around the circle so the three solutions cut the circle in three equal parts.  It's a *very* useful observation.

Comment: In other words:  If you have $z^3 = a+bi$ there will be three roots.  All of them will be of size $\sqrt[3]{|a+bi|}$.  The angles will cut a circle in $3$ and be $120$ degrees apart.  If you turn $a,b$ into an angle (how?) one angle will be a $\frac 13$ that.  The other two will be $\frac {2\pi}3$ apart.  It's neat once you grok it!

Comment: @Edison You're right.

Answer (score 3):

$$z^3=-8i\iff
\begin{cases}
|z|^3=|-8i|=8\\
\arg{z^3}=3\arg z=-\dfrac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi
\end{cases}$$
$\iff$ 
$$
\begin{cases}
|z|=2\\
\arg{z}=-\dfrac{\pi}{6}+\dfrac{2\pi}{3}k, \quad k\in\{0,1,2\}
\end{cases}$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: What does your arg mean?

Comment: If you view $z = a + bi$ as an angle, $\theta$, and distance, $r$, so that $z = r(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)$ then the relation between $z$ and the angle $\theta$ is said to be "$\theta$ is the argument of $z$".  Or $\arg z = \theta$.

Comment: This makes more sense now. Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

Well, $-8i=2^3\exp\frac{-i\pi}{2}$, so one cube root is $2\exp\frac{-i\pi}{6}$. You can get the rest yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I took a rather *naive* approach.

\begin{align}
z^3+8i&=0\\
(z)^3-(2i)^3&=0\\
(z-2i)(z^2+2iz+4i^2)&=0\\
(z-2i)(z^2+2iz-4)&=0
\end{align}

\begin{align}
z&=\frac{-(2i)\pm\sqrt{(2i)^2-4(1)(-4)}}{2}\\
z&=\frac{-2i\pm\sqrt{-4+16}}{2}\\
z&=\frac{-2i\pm\sqrt{12}}{2}\\
z&=-i\pm\sqrt3
\end{align}

The solution set is therefore $z=2i$, $z=\sqrt3-i$, and $z=-\sqrt3-i$.

Comment: It works.  I would say for problems in general like this, finding complex roots, this is not a great approach.  But, as soon as I saw the problem I saw it was a difference of cubes and so I immediately thought of this before the more standard complex analysis.

Comment: Thanks for confirming!

Comment: Thanks for sharing your perspective on the solution. I was considering an attempt like this initially, so I am glad to see that it works.

Answer (score 1):

For questions like these the Euler form works the best.
Substitute $z=re^{i\theta}$ to get $r^3e^{3i\theta+2n\pi}=-8i$
Now take cube root on both sides then different values of $n$ would give you different values of $z$.

Answer (score 1):

You have $r^3(\cos(3\theta)+i\sin(3\theta))=c$ with $\theta\in\Bbb R,r\in[0,\infty)$, therefore you have to go $$\begin{cases}r^3=\lvert c\rvert\\ \cos(3\theta)=\frac1{\lvert c\rvert}\Re c\\ \sin(3\theta)=\frac1{\lvert c\rvert}\Im c\end{cases}$$

Comment: Can you please explain this a bit further? Your notation seems a bit new to me.

Comment: The R and I just indicate the real and imaginary components of the complex number c

Comment: If $c = a + bi$ then $Re(z) =a$ and $Im(c) = b$.  ANd $Re(c) = a = r^3\cos(3\theta)$ and $Im(c) =b = r^3\sin(3\theta)$.  So $r^3 = |c|$ and $\cos(\theta) = \frac 1{|c|}a =\frac 1{|c|}Re(c)$ etc.

Comment: I see that better now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$(r^3(\cos(3\theta)+i\sin(3\theta)) +8i=0$

So continue:

$(r^3(\cos(3\theta)+i\sin(3\theta)) = -8i= 8(0 + i(-1))$

$(r^3(\cos(3\theta)+i\sin(3\theta)) = 8((\cos \frac {3\pi}2+2k\pi) + i\sin(\frac{3\pi}2+2k\pi))$

So $r^3 = 8$ and $3\theta = \frac {3\pi}2 + 2k\pi$

So $r =2$ and $\theta = \frac \pi 2 + \frac 23k\pi$

So there are three solutions:

1)if $k =0$ then $2(\cos \frac \pi 2 + i\sin \frac \pi 2) = 2i$.

Check.   $(2i)^3 = 2^3i^2 = 8*i^2 *i = -8i$.  That's good.

2) if $k = 1$ then $2(\cos (\frac \pi 2+\frac {2\pi} 3) + i \sin (\frac \pi 2+\frac {2\pi} 3))= 2(\cos \frac {7\pi}6) + i\sin \frac {7\pi}6) = -\sqrt 3 - i$.

Check:  $(-\sqrt 3-i)^3 = -[(\sqrt 3)^3 + 3(\sqrt 3)^2i + 3(\sqrt 3)i^2 + i^3] = $

$-[3\sqrt 3 + 9i - 3\sqrt 3 - i] = 8i$.  It works.

and if $k = 2$ then 3) $2(\cos (\frac \pi 2+\frac {4\pi} 3) + i \sin (\frac \pi 2+\frac {4\pi} 3))= 2(\cos \frac {11\pi}6) + i\sin \frac {11\pi}6) = \sqrt 3 - i$.

Check:  $(\sqrt 3-i)^3 = (-\sqrt 3)^3 + 3(-\sqrt 3)^2i + 3(-\sqrt 3)i^2 + i^3] = $

$-3\sqrt 3 - 9i +3\sqrt 3 + i = -8i$.  It works.

Comment: How did you arrive to your third mathematical line?

Comment: $8i = 8(0 + i(-1))= 8(\cos \phi + i\sin \phi)$  for some $\phi$ where $\cos \phi =0$ and $\sin \phi =-1$.  And that has solutions where $\phi = \frac {3\pi}2 + 2k\pi$.  So that's the result.

Comment: This makes more sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could just eyeball it and see that $2^3=8, i^3=-i$

so $(2i)^3=-8i$ so the solutions are $2i, 2i\omega, $ and $2i\omega^2$, where $\omega$ is a complex cube root of $1$.

But to continue your way,  $r^3(\cos(3\theta)+i\sin(3\theta))=-8i \implies r^3=8$ and $\sin(3\theta)=-1,$

i.e., $3\theta=\dfrac{3\pi}2+n2\pi$, so $\theta=\dfrac{\pi}2+\dfrac{2n}3\pi,$

so solutions are $2\exp\dfrac{i\pi}2=2i, 2\exp\dfrac{i7\pi}6=-\sqrt3-i,$ and $2\exp\dfrac{i11\pi}6=\sqrt3-i,$

Comment: I can definitely see that, now that you pointed it out. Thank you.